# Create a Context View in Drupal and then display in Panel based on NID (node id)

Tags: drupal, view, panel

I have a quick question. I am sure it is easy to do but I am missing something.

How do I create a View Context of All Content/Node Types. Then I want to display my nodes in Panel 3 based on NID/Node ID? Is this the right way to go?

Background:

There are many teachers as Content Types. There is a page for all teachers eg
www.example.com/all-teachers. If a user clicks on "a particular teacher" from this page they should be taken to:

www.example.com/teacher-name - this page should display contents from "this teacher".

Please ask if my question is not clear and thank you so much for your help.

---

Thank you for your reply.

The Panel 3 part is only to have a custom layout page. I am using 960grid to display the content. I want to display dynamic content in the panel based on NODE ID.

The way to do this is to create a View and pass an argument which will be Node ID. Then in Panel 3 you can create the Context (View). This allows you to put fields from the node on seperate content panes.

The URL displayed will be based on the Node ID.  Its basically like creating 1 template for many different teacher details.  I am not sure how to explain it in technical term but I hope you get the idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need panels at all. Can't the view just link each teacher to it's node? If you want to control how a teacher node is displayed why not use something like [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds).

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thank you for your reply. The Panel part is only to have a custom layout page. I am using 960grid to display the content.